# Printing bold text on an Epson printer

Tags: java, android

I am developing an android application for a company where they can make collections and invoices.

currently the application prints without any kind of special character

How can I change the font size and make the titles bold?

Printer reference: Epson Tm-p80
Model: M316B

Code used:

```
 txtPrt = new TxtPrt(compartir,"");
 txtPrt.setFont('C');
 txtPrt.writeLn("Prueba FontB -------------------------------------","");
 print();
 txtPrt.setFont('X');
 txtPrt.writeLn("Prueba FontA -------------------------------------", "");
 print();
```

Print Method:

```
private void print() {
  if (impFactura != null)
            try {
                impFactura.mmOutputStream.write(txtPrt.Txt.getBytes());
                txtPrt.Txt = "";
                pausar();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                alertErrorImpre();
            }
    }
```

Comment: You'll need to provide information on what library / code you're currently using.

Comment: Already add the used code

Comment: What is `TxtPrt`? What is `impFactura`? You need to provide us with enough info to actually fix your issue!